# Issue with facebook login and the php-sdk : callback page is loaded twice

Tags: php, facebook, authorization, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

So I posted a question the other day about a bug I was having while trying to implement facebook login using the facebook php-sdk on my site: [After changing website domain, facebook login returns error "This authorization code has been used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812190/after-changing-website-domain-facebook-login-returns-error-this-authorization) . I've been getting an error message "This authorization code has been used" on my callback page (see below).

However, I set up a counter (see code below) using a session on the page to see how often it was being loaded. In fact, I found the page was being loaded twice each time I clicked the login button, and therefore the authorisation code is being loaded twice on two pages, resulting in the error. My problem now is solving why the page loads twice. If anyone can tell me I would be very grateful.

If it helps, here is my code.

/index.php

```
<?php

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{APP ID}',
  'app_secret' => '{APP SECRET}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.1',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$fbLink = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://{domain}/facebook-callback.php', $permissions);

?>

<a href="<?php echo $fbLink; ?>">Login</a>
```

/facebook-callback.php

```
<?php

session_start();

//session counter (note: this increments 2 each time, when it should only increment 1)
if (isset($_SESSION["counter"])) {
  $_SESSION["counter"] = $_SESSION["counter"]+1;
} else {
  $_SESSION["counter"] = 0;
}

echo $_SESSION["counter"];

if (($loader = require_once '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php') == null)  {
  die('Vendor directory not found, Please run composer install.');
}

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app secret}'
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

...
//My code is longer than this but I get the error from the try statement above, so I did not think it necessary to add it here.
?>
```

Hope I've given enough information. I will praise whoever finds an answer to this, as I've been struggling with it for days now.

Comment: why don't you edit your previous question with your new update instead of adding the same question?

Comment: it was mostly because i found a new issue but also because i was afraid no one would see it if i edited. do you know if it gets added back in the "newest" questions when an edit is made?

Comment: A common cause for a page URL being unexpectedly requested twice by the browser, is an img/script/link element (or other external resource) with an empty src or href attribute. An “empty” relative URL resolves to the current absolute URL. HTML5 has specified how browsers are supposed to handle this (spot the situation, and not make a second request), but I am not sure all browser do it that way already. So go check your page source code for stuff like that.